# variable value becomes undefined in NodeJS after if cycle

Tags: javascript, node.js, postgresql

HI I have some code to get a json value from my db and then add it to an object but in my if cycle it has the value  `{"isRoot": "true", "visible": "true"}` but after the cycle i do a console.log to this and get undefined...

```
Database.Services.getServicesMapInfoById(device.id).then(function(mapData){
        if(mapData!=undefined){
            var map = mapData.map;
            console.log("sendDeviceInfo map  >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> ", map);
            sendData.map=map;
            resolve(sendData);
        } else {
            resolve(null);
        }
    }).catch(function (e) {
        createLog('error', __dirname, __filename.slice(__dirname.length + 1, -3), device.id, 'sendDeviceInfo','FATAL',e);
        return reject(e);
    });
```

console.log("sendDeviceInfo map --------------------------------->", sendData.map);

Logs:

```
sendDeviceInfo getServicesMapInfoById map  >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> {"isRoot": "true", "visible": "true"}

sendDeviceInfo map ---------------------------------> undefined
```

Can anyone help me? I'm returning the value of map with Promises using resolve but this didn't solve my problem...

Comment: The function is asynchronous. It might not complete until after you log it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why is my variable unaltered after I modify it inside of a function? - Asynchronous code reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23667086/why-is-my-variable-unaltered-after-i-modify-it-inside-of-a-function-asynchron)

Comment: How can i make it ? I dont get it..

Comment: promises are asynchronous, `        console.log("sendDeviceInfo map --------------------------------->",map);` will always execute before any async code.

Comment: Maybe the best is to create a array of promises and then execute all with Promise.all ? Im new at node not very good with promises

Comment: I can see the log `sendDeviceInfo getServicesMapInfoById map  >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>` ptinted before `sendDeviceInfo map ---` it mean `map` has initialize and `getServicesMapInfoById` is "not async" in this case, but `return resolve(map);` recently `resolve` function is blackbox which mayby  unset `map` variable